# A documentation to refer about JSON, cURL and laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, curl

But I have a basic knowledge about laravel, php, mysql.
JSON and cURL, I'm still studying.

However, I watched the following youtube video and got a rough understanding about jSON and cURL.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3gz5K9YefY

I am currently making a software using laravel. I want to make the connections to database etc using json.

I want to refer a document on using JSON in laravel

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#json-responses not good enough for you?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this tutorial can help you: http://vegibit.com/json-in-laravel/